# Apply NavItem active class for two different routes in react router.

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a nav bar in reactJs/ router app like the following,

```
<Nav>
    <LinkContainer exact to="/dashboard">
        <NavItem>Dashboard</NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
    <LinkContainer to="/contract">
        <NavItem>Contract</NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

Under some cases, when the user visits `/contract` and for that user if there is only one contract, then the link will be redirected to `/contractDetail` page. When this happens, I still want my `<NavItem>Contract</NavItem>` to be highlighted / have active class. However, this is not working now because there is no `<NavItem>` for `contractDetail`.

I am not sure how this can be implemented, any help will be appreciated. NOTE: This is working when on the link `/dashboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With React-Router-Dom you can define custom logic for displaying a NavLink as active. Here's [a link to the entry](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func) in the docs